# Airflow scheduling, re-run failed task

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am fairly new to airflow, although I have been able to write code for reads(datastore) and writes(bigquery).
I am not able to get going with scheduling my jobs/tasks.
I would like to run the job every 2 hours, read data from a source for previous 2 hours.
Now, if a task fails, i would like to manually retry it, but for the particular 2 hours it was meant to run for. How do i accomplish this? 
I have couple of things in mind:

- Store job-id and time range it was scheduled to run. And on retries i can read it, from sqlite or some other database.
- Airflow has an inbuilt variable which points to the meant to be execution time for that job, which I can use in my code.

Should i consider some other option? or any of the above?

Comment: Can you post [a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your DAG script and explain what does not work in it as you expect?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you're using current datetime (like now()) in your task, do you?

The good practice is to use the value of `execution_date` in Airflow Context instead of call datetime.now() in your operator, as the `execution_date` of a schedule job will not be changed even you re-execute the DAG/tasks.

Comment: Yes, i fugured that out, I was hoping there should be some some context based internal  variable. Thanks